# Show that the equation $x^d=a$ has solution for every $a \in G$ if and only if $(d,|G|)=1$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group show that the equation $x^d=a$ has solution for every $a \in G$ if and only if $\gcd(d,|G|)=1$

I prove

$\Leftarrow ) $ if $\gcd(d,|G|)=1$ then exists $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$pd+q|G|=1$$
And now let $a \in G$ arbitrary then
$$a^{pd+q|G|}=a^1 \Rightarrow (a^p)^d (a^q)^{|G|}=a \Rightarrow (a^p)^d=a$$
Then putting $x=a^p$, $x$ is solution.

To prove the next direction I think in the division algorithm or maybe the euclidean algorithm but not works, i not sure how work with these direction.

Any hint or help I will be very grateful.

Comment: This is equivalent to $x\mapsto x^d$ being injective, since $G$ is finite. Now it follows from Cauchy's theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proof:

Let $G=\{e,a_1,...,a_{n-1}\}$, where $a_i\neq e$ for $ i=1,2...,n-1$, so $|G|=n$

$"\Rightarrow"$ List solutions,

$$e^d=e,~~ x_1^d=a_1,~~...,~~x_{n-1}^d=a_{n-1}$$

where $x_i\neq e$,  for $ i, j=1,2,...,n-1$, and $x_i\neq x_j$ whenever $i\neq j.$

Assume $k=\gcd(d,n)>1$, then there exists a prime $p$, such that $p\mid k$, hence, $p\mid d$. Let $d=p\cdot h$.

By Cauchy theorem, there exists an element $x_j\in\{x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1}\}$, such that $x_j^p=e$. Further, we have
$$x_j^d=a_j\Rightarrow x_j^d=(x_j^p)^h=e^h=e=a_j$$
So we get contradictions with $a_i\neq e$ for $ i=1,2...,n-1$

$"\Leftarrow"$ you have done it.